# Python, Tkinter - some general questions about the code

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some general questions regarding working code below:

1. tkinter is library for graphic interface as I understand I can use it interchangeably with for example Kivy?
2. Would it be better to learn Kivy instead or other?
3. Lines `import tkinter as tk` and `from tkinter import *` do exactly the same, in the first one I have alias though?
4. In the code below, why do I have to use ttk in `ttk.Progressbar`?
   I imported whole library with `import tkinter as tk` so why do i have to reimport ttk just    for progress bar? (otherwise it is not working). I would expect to work sth. like `tk.Progressbar`
5. In the line `btnProg = tk.Button(self.root, text = 'update', command=self.fnUpdateProgress)`, why method "fnUpdateProgress" can't have any variables? Whenever I add any, the button stop working? -> for example `btnProg = tk.Button(self.root, text = 'update', command=self.fnUpdateProgress(24))` (ofc then some changes in def of the method itself)
6. I created progress bar (pb) as attribute of the class Test, but wolud it be better to define it as regular variable (without self)? To be honest, code works exactly the same.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk    
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

from CreateProgramMain import main
import GlobalVariables

class Test():
    ####################################################################################
    def __init__(self):
        self.Progress=0
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title(GlobalVariables.strAppName)
        self.root.geometry('400x200')
    
        lbl = Label(self.root, text="Please choose environment.",font=("Arial Bold", 12))
        lbl.grid(column=2, row=0,sticky='e') 

        def btnTestClicked():
            main("TEST",self)
        btnTest=tk.Button(self.root, text="Test Environment", command=btnTestClicked)
        btnTest.grid(column=2, row=15)

        #Place progress bar
        pb = ttk.Progressbar(self.root,orient='horizontal',mode='determinate',length=200)
        pb.grid(column=1, row=65, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=20)    
        pb["value"]=self.Progress
        pb["maximum"]=100

        btnProg = tk.Button(self.root, text = 'update', command=self.fnUpdateProgress)
        btnProg.grid(column=2, row=75)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def fnUpdateProgress(self): #why i cant insert variable inside?
            pb["value"]=self.Progress
            self.Progress=self.Progress+5
            pb.update()
app = Test()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. it is upto you. However, `tkinter` and `kivy` both have their own syntaxes, commands, and their own usages. It might be a little difficult to convert `tkinter` code to `kivy`.
2. it is upto you
3. Yes. In the first, you have imported `tkinter` as `tk`. In the second one. You have done a wild card import. You have imported everything
4. Tkinter is a folder containing various modules. It contains a file called `ttk.py` which you have to import to access `ttk`.

All other classes like `Label`, `Entry`, `Tk` is present in `__init__.py`

5. you have to use lambda for it. If you call the function, it will be executed wlright away and the returned value is kept as the command.

Doing `command=self.fnUpdateProgress(24))` will execute the function right away. Then, the returned value is kept as a command. Here, it returns `None`. So the command is nothing or the button is useless.

Use a `lambda`  expression `command=lambda: self.fnUpdateProgress(24))`

6. if you don't add `self` it will be local to the function only. To access ot outside, it would have to be declared global, which is the point to avoid while using classes

Comment: "_tkinter is library for graphic interface as I understand I can use it interchangeably with for example Kivy?_": Is your answer to this, "_it is upto you._"? It is something not possible to transfer projects made in tkinter to Kivy(like how qtdesigner provides python and cpp codes).

Comment: @CoolCloud Maybe I misunderstood the question